# How to make UITableViewCell Size according to the height of the image in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with an `UIImageView` inside it. What constraints should I add so that the cell height dynamically changes according to the image height. The images in the `ImageView` of varying heights, so I don't want to fix the height of `UIImageView`

Comment: what have you done so far so share to get answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a delegate to define the height of each row. I don't know if there is another solution which is faster.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //get UIImage of the image for this row
        //and return image height
        if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "") {
            return img.size.height
        } else {
            return DEFAULT_HEIGHT
        }
    }
```

If you have to download from internet, you should define a default_heigth for that delegate call-back. Then, when the image is downloaded, you call reloadTable on the associated index path with new height from downloaded image